# Calculating the week number of a year in Excel

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to calculate the week number of a week in a year in excel using the formula `=WEEKNUM(A1,2)`.

My Result:

```
----------------------
|  Date    |   Week  |
|2021-01-01|    1    |
|2021-01-02|    1    |
|2021-01-03|    1    |
|2021-01-04|    1    |
|2021-01-05|    1    |
|2021-01-06|    1    |
|2021-01-07|    1    |
----------------------
```

Result which I want:

```
----------------------
|  Date    |   Week  |
|2021-01-01|    53   |
|2021-01-02|    53   |
|2021-01-03|    53   |
|2021-01-04|    1    |
|2021-01-05|    1    |
|2021-01-06|    1    |
|2021-01-07|    1    |
----------------------
```

Since Date 1,2,3 are in the last week of the last year.

How do I get the above result

Comment: Find the first Monday of the year and if the date is greater than the 1st of january  and less than the first monday return 53, else the weeknum.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm bit confused. So, I need to find the date of first Monday of the year and then compare it with the 1st of January. If it is less than first monday then return 53 else the weeknum. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If it is between the 1st of January and the first Monday of the year then 53 else weeknum.

Comment: There are many examples how to find the first weekday of the month. Then a simple IF(AND(),,)

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you want `ISOWEEKNUM(A1)` where the first day of a week is Monday, and the first week of a year includes at least four days of that year.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That is one of the formulas I have never used.  I learnt me something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @ScottCraner comment, I was able to get the result. Here is my excel formula.

```
=IF(AND(A1>=DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1),A1<DATE(YEAR(A1),1,8)-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),1,6))),53,WEEKNUM(A1,2))
```